# SQL CE query problem: Update blob from file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I couldn't query below, there is an error:

> The Derived Table SQL construct or statement is not supported.

```
   UPDATE [personList] 
   SET [personPhoto] = (   
      SELECT BulkColumn FROM 
         OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\99309.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
   )
   WHERE [personID] = '99309'
```

What am I missing? Is the syntax supported in SQL CE?

MS-SQL CE 3.5

Comment: I would assume this is because you are doing a `SELECT *` in the sub query, whereas you could have multiple rows and/or fields returned.  Have you tried selecting only a single field, and a single result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPENROWSET is not supported by SQL Server Compact.